# How to emit values into timer creation function RXJS & Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to create a retry config for `retry` after `catchError`. I need to send specific delays based on values in an array. I want to be able to take each value from the array and send them individually to a timer creation function.

So for example:

```
numberArr = [1000, 2000, 3000]
```

timer is called with `timer(1000)`, then `timer(2000)`, then `timer(3000)`

Using `concatMap` only uses the first value, `switchMap` the last, but I am unsure of what to use to take each emitted number and use that value for the timer function.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

```
   private ob$ = of(1);

   private retryConfig: {
     matcher: () => void;
     retryWaits: number[];
   };

   constructor() {}

   private setRetryConfig(): RetryConfig {
    this.retryConfig = {
      matcher: () => {},
      retryWaits: [3000, 4000, 6000],
    };

    const delayObservable$ = from(this.retryConfig.retryWaits)

    const delayFunction = delayObservable$.pipe(
      tap(() => console.time()),
      tap((x) => console.log('delay', x)),
      concatMap((number) => timer(number)), // this is where I am seeing a problem
      take(this.retryConfig.retryWaits.length),
      tap(() => console.timeEnd()) // this is alway logging 3000ish milliseconds
    );

    return {
      count: this.retryConfig.retryWaits.length,
      delay: () => delayFunction,
    };
  }

   ngOnInit(): void {
    this.ob$
      .pipe(
        tap(() => {
          throw throwError(() => new Error('error'));
        }),
        catchError((error) => throwError(() => new Error(error))),
        retry(this.setRetryConfig())
      )
      .subscribe((x) => {
        if (x) {
          throw throwError(() => new Error('error'));
        }
      });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `delay` function gets called everytime the error is thrown. We can't use the array of numbers to wait x times. Instead, we need to use whatever the *current* retry-wait value is and wait once.

We can achieve this by calling `timer` in the `delay` callback and passing it the first element of `retryWaits` simultaneously removing it from the array.

```
const setRetryConfig = () => {
  const retryConfig = {
      matcher: () => {},
      retryWaits: [3000, 4000, 6000],
  };

  return {
    count: retryConfig.retryWaits.length,
    delay: () => timer(retryConfig.retryWaits.shift())
  } 
}
```

Also note that throwing an `Error` inside a `tap` might not work. I threw the error in a `mergeMap` instead.

```
of(0).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => {
    console.log("trying")
    return throwError(() => 'Error!');
  }),
  retry(setRetryConfig())
).subscribe(r => console.log("Result", r))
```

This outputs:

```
trying
---0s---
---1s---
---2s---
trying
---3s---
---4s---
---5s---
---6s---
---7s---
trying
---8s---
---9s---
---10s---
---11s---
---12s---
---13s---
---14s---
trying
---15s---
Error!
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for this. When setting timer as the callback and passing ...retryWaits.shift() <-- are you seeing an error?

Comment: @DevDevDev - no, what are you getting?

Comment: delay: () => timer(this.retryConfig.retryWaits.shift()),

gives me: 

Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number | Date'.

Comment: @DevDevDev - Ah, did not notice that you are using TypeScript ;) . We know the array can't be empty at this point. So putting an `!` null assertion operator should be sufficient `this.retryConfig.retryWaits.shift()!`.

Comment: Also I would recommend to *not* store `retryConfig` in `this`. You would not want to share it between multiple Observables. Just use a local variable as I did. If you want to use the same config between different Observables, copy the `retryWaits` array for each Observable.